# Random cardinality of rows per parent row

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

I'm generating some test data for a client in the form of `Customer -< Booking` and what I'm trying to achieve is to generate a random number of Bookings per Customer (between 1 and 25).

Having already generated test data for the `Customer` table, I figured I could use `n <= ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25` as a join condition to a numbers table to produce the random cardinality per row, however my attempt must be highly suboptimal because it's taking over 15 minutes to return. Ideally I'd like to reduce this to below 2 minutes, if possible.

My cobbled attempt is as follows:

```
;WITH CTE_BookingCounts AS (
  SELECT
    CustomerId,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25 AS R
  FROM dbo.Customer
)
SELECT
  B.CustomerId,
  N.n AS BookingIndex
FROM dbo.Customer C
INNER JOIN CTE_BookingCounts BC ON BC.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
INNER JOIN #numbers N ON N.n <= BC.R;
```

Please could anyone suggest how I can restructure this query or even an entirely different approach, if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a random number for each row, how about this?

```
SELECT B.CustomerId, n.n AS BookingIndex
FROM dbo.Customer C INNER JOIN
     #numbers n 
     ON rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 25 - 1 <= n.n;
```

The `-1` is to ensure that at least one row is selected.

I should note that this recalculates the values for each row in `BC`.  This might actually be better for your purposes:

```
SELECT B.CustomerId, n.n AS BookingIndex
FROM (SELECT C.*, rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 25 + 1 as numrows
      FROM dbo.Customer C
     ) C INNER JOIN
     #numbrers n
     ON n.n <= numrows;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm confused as to whether you're suggesting I should drop the CTE or the #numbers table.

Comment: @ChrisPickford . . . I was confused myself.  The idea is to get rid of the CTE, not the numbers table.